# How to parse Float to String exactly?

Tags: java, string

As the title said:

I tried:

```
        Float.toString(float);
        String.valueOf(float);
        Float.toHexString(float);
        float.toString();
```

But I found if the Float value = 100.00;
Covert to String value will be 100.0.
How to avoid it? How to be exactly?

Thanks in advance.

Edits-------------

The answers are point to that those which specific the decimal places.

Comment: `But I found if the Float value = 100.00; If String value will be 100.0.` Confusing.

Comment: what u want 100 or 100.00 ?

Comment: You know, that "exact" is a quite broad term, when using floating point arithmetic?

Comment: Using the word **exact** in the context of **floating numbers** triggers me to link [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Pawanmishra what i want is when i set the float value = 100.0, it will output 100.0, when the float value = 100.00,it will be 100.00.So is this can implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be exact, you'd better try to format your Float to String using the NumberFormat class hierarchy : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Its "stupid" to keep 2 zeros at the end. All you've to do is add as many zeros as needed at the moment you're printing it, but internally, it's going to be saved as `x.0`

Example:

```
printf ("%.2f", 3.14159);
```

Prints:

> 3.14

Answer (score 0):

if you are bent upon doing this..

when you get str = "100.0";

```
 String[] strNew = str.split(".");

 if(strNew[1].length==1)
 {
 str=str+"0";
 }
```

> BTW A VERY BAD WAY ...

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 100.00000f;
String expected = String.format("%.6f", f);
```

The output of this will be :

> 100.000000

The length of the numbers after the floating point is done by you.

> String.format("%.6f", f)  == 100.000000
>
> String.format("%.2f", f)  == 100.00